# MariaDB: Verify if a certain value exists in table1.id before inserting into table2

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery

**Objective:** Verify the existence of an ID string in table1; if yes, insert data into table2, else skip.

I have two tables in a MariaDB db :

**table1**

| id int(11) auto_increment | myIDString text |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1234 |

**table2**

| id int(11) auto_increment | myIDString text | string1 char(32) | string2 char(32) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0123 | Some text 1 | Some text 2 |

Obviously, they are not similar but common for both is a column named myIDString. As data is being processed, table1 is populated first and I get a certain value in myIDString (here 1234).

Further on in the processing I get data variables to feed into table2.string1 and table2.string2.

If at all possible, I try to create a one line Insert like

```
if exists (select myIDString from table1 where myIDSTring = 1234) then 
insert into table2(myIDString, string1, string2) values(1234, $myString1,$myString2);
```

But so far no luck. I've read posts concerning similar problem and those offered no solution to this.
Optimally, I would want a oneliner solution, but secondly, in case I need a trigger to handle this, how would one such look like?

Comment: it is easier to make the myIDString  unique

Comment: Why not create a foreign key for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution for my issue is to use a trigger.

```
DELIMITER //                                                                                                            CREATE TRIGGER threadIDcheck                                                                                            BEFORE INSERT ON myID2                                                                                                  FOR EACH ROW                                                                                                            BEGIN                                                                                                                   IF NEW.threadID1 NOT IN (select threadID1 from myID1) THEN                                                              SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'That myIDString does not exist in table1';                                         END IF;                                                                                                                 END; //                                                                                                                 DELIMITER ;  DELIMITER //                                                                                                            CREATE TRIGGER threadIDcheck                                                                                            BEFORE INSERT ON myID2                                                                                                  FOR EACH ROW                                                                                                            BEGIN                                                                                                                   IF NEW.threadID1 NOT IN (select threadID1 from myID1) THEN                                                              SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ThreadID does not exist in table1';                                         END IF;                                                                                                                 END; //                                                                                                                 DELIMITER ;  DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER threadIDcheck
BEFORE INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.myIDString NOT IN (select myIDString from table1) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'That myIDString value does not exist in table1';
END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I do a simple `insert into table2(myIDString) values(1111);` and that value is not in table1, then the insert fails gracefully.
Should anyone have some other solution, please feel free to add it in here :).